# Angular JS, how to have two seperate "main" displays that can both change frequently

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular with Node to create a Web-APP. The back-end will be building a standard JSON RESTful API, and that is going normally. As for the front end, I am running into a little bit of problems. So my website is designed in a way where there are essentially TWO main displays. Eg. Two windows inside the website that can change frequently. I have NO IDEA how I should implement this! So far I have split my website into directives, eg each "display window" is its own directive, and I was thinking maybe use $localStorage and just have a bunch of ng-ifs inside each HTML file for each directive, switching the view depending on some value in $localStorage. Eg. Person clicks a button, some value in local storage changes to 10, an ng-if inside the directive displays the correct "view" inside the display because the value 10 represents some view. The problem is that I will have to put ALL my HTML in one file, and Im not even sure if this will work! Any suggestions? Any help appreciated!

PS. The two "main displays" can change without the other one changing, hence why I didnt want to group them into 1 view. They are separate entities, and programatically it makes more sense to split them up! They are also physically seperated on the screen (bottom right and top right, seperated by a bar)

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to give you a solid answer without more to go on. What directives do you currently have? What do the displays look like? _How_ do you want the displays to change?

Comment: I have a directive called "display" for one view, and a directive called "hud" for the other view. Imagine that they can both change independetently of each other, not just the data inside them, but also the format of the html. So the html is COMPLETELY different when they change. How do I implement this?

Comment: Why don't you give a try to ng-show directive? Why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: That's what I meant basically. So you think I should put all the html in one file and then have like 20 different ng-shows?

Comment: If if i understood right, "two "main displays" could be your to main Div and use ng-show/ng-hide directive on it. What you think?

Comment: Sorry I think I expained poorly! Both divs are always visible! They are two parts of the website that are frequently changing. Each "window/div/section/area" can be 1 of 20 different possiblities. Is the best way in Angular to use 20 different ng-shows for each one and have a global variable dictating what state you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying two separates views in the same page, you have to use [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) because the native [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) directive only supports one.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!